# Graphics freeze after updating to a new kernel (5.19) in Fedora 36

Tags: fedora, kernel, graphics, intel-graphics

I am using Fedora 36 in a Dell Latitude 7430 laptop. These are the specs of my computer as per neofetch:

[image]

I have recently updated the kernel to the latest version (5.19.16) using dnf and since then the graphics of my computer freeze if it is not plugged to an external monitor. However, everything displays correctly on a external screen when I plug my computer to it (although there is a large delay between the external and the laptop screens).

I've tried updating to the latest development kernel (6.1.0 as in the screenshot) to see if that would solve my issue but it persists nonetheless.

I didn't have any issues with version 5.17.5 of the kernel which I am still using as my daily driver. What might be causing these issues? I guess it is related with the UHD screen of the laptop, as I don't have issues when using an external monitor. How can I fix them?

Comment: Report here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues

Comment: fist is to get so kind of log, without a log we can only prohesize